# CSS button with a link

Tags: css, url, button, hyperlink

I use the code below to get the button. The new window opens but the whole URL is never passed. It links to my Google Drive shareable link (visible by anyone with a link) but the window provides me with a 404 not found page. Any ideas?

```
<form action="some URL" target="_blank">
<input type="submit" target="_blank" value="Click Here" /></form>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want a link on a button, don't use a form, but something like this:

```css
button {
width: 100px;
height: 60px;
background: #fa4;
border-radius: 5px;
font-family: "Arial";
font-size: 24px;
border: 5px solid #afd;
}
```

```html
<a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank"><button type="button">Click</button></a>
```

Comment: Thanks, I was looking at something little more  'fancy' but without writing the entire CSS class to change every link on the website.

Comment: what has styling got to do with using a form? you just need *one* CSS rule to style all buttons - see example above (I admit - could look better ;-)

Comment: It's down to the very specific use of the button in my case. I only need to add a single button here and there, which goes across the entire page. The form I used matched the layout I wanted perfectly, just couldn't get it to wok.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I solved it with this:

```
<form method="POST" action="url" target="_blank"><input type="submit" value="Click Me"></form>
```

Comment: and what about this is "fancy" and styled? I don't understand your comment to my answer above...